# Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_children() on null

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I created a shortcode and added it to the variable single product page using `woocommerce_available_variation` hook.

```
function customize_woocommerce_available_variation( $variation_data, $product, $variation ) {
    $variation_data['form__data'] = do_shortcode( '[form__data]' );
    return $variation_data;
} add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'customize_woocommerce_available_variation', 10, 3 );
```

path : /woocommerce/single-product/add-to-cart/variation.php

```
{{{ data.variation.form__data }}}
```

and

```
function form__data() {
    global $product;
    $variations_id = $product->get_children();
    foreach ( $variations_id as $variation_id ) {
        $variation = wc_get_product( $variation_id );
        if ( ! $variation->is_in_stock() ) {
            $product_url = get_permalink( $variation_id );
            $url = wp_nonce_url( $product_url, 'action_waitlist' );
            $url = add_query_arg( 'wsn_waitlist_users', $variation_id, $url );
            $url = add_query_arg( 'wsn_waitlist_users' . '-action', 'register', $url );
            $url = add_query_arg( 'var_id', $variation_id, $url );
            $is_loggedin = is_user_logged_in();
            ob_start();
            if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
                    ?>
                    <div class="wsn-form">
                        <div class="wsn-form__inner">
                            <div class="wsn-form__content">
                                <div class="wsn-form-message">
                                    <div class="wsn-form-message-item"><?php echo apply_filters( 'wsn-out-of-stock', esc_html__( 'Out of Stock', 'in-stock-notifier' ), $is_loggedin ) ?></div>
                                    <div class="wsn-form-message-item"><?php echo apply_filters( 'wsn-guide-desc', esc_html__( 'Provide your Email so we can email you when product comes in-stock.', 'in-stock-notifier' ), $is_loggedin ); ?></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="wsn-form-field">
                                    <input type="text" placeholder="<?php echo __( 'Enter Your Email Address...', 'in-stock-notifier' ); ?>" id="wsn_waitlist_email" name="wsn_email" class="wsn-input-field wsn-waitlist-email-field"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="wsn-form__footer">
                                <a class="<?php echo apply_filters( 'join_btn_classes', 'button btn alt wsn-submit-form wsn-submit-form--disabled', $is_loggedin ); ?>" href="<?php echo esc_url( $url ); ?>"><?php echo esc_attr__( 'Join waitlist', 'in-stock-notifier' ); ?></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php
            } else {
                $user = wp_get_current_user();
                $email = $user->user_email;
                $waitlist = wsn_get_waitlist( $variation_id );
                $joined = wsn_check_register( $email, $waitlist );
                ?>
                <div class="wsn-form">
                    <div class="wsn-form__inner">
                        <div class="wsn-form__content">
                            <div class="wsn-form-message">
                                <div class="wsn-form-message-item">
                                    <?php echo esc_html__( 'Out of Stock', 'in-stock-notifier' ); ?>
                                </div>
                                <div class="wsn-form-message-item">
                                    <?php echo $joined ?
                                        esc_html( apply_filters( 'wsn_leave_waitlist_message_text', esc_attr__( 'We\'ll notify you as soon as item is back in stock.', 'in-stock-notifier' ), $is_loggedin ) ) :
                                        esc_html( apply_filters( 'wsn_join_waitlist_message_text', esc_attr__( 'Join the waitlist, so we can notify you as soon as the item is back in stock.', 'in-stock-notifier' ), $is_loggedin ) );
                                    ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="wsn-form__footer">
                            <?php if ( $joined ) {
                                $url = add_query_arg( 'wsn_waitlist_users' . '-action', 'leave', $url );
                                $url = add_query_arg( 'wsn_email', $email, $url );
                                ?>
                                <a class="button btn alt wsn_button <?php echo esc_html( apply_filters( 'wsn_leave_waitlist_button_classes', 'wsn_leaveclass', $is_loggedin ) ); ?>" href="<?php echo esc_url( esc_attr( $url ) ); ?>"><?php echo get_option( 'leave_btn_label', __( 'Leave waitlist', 'in-stock-notifier' ) ); ?></a>
                            <?php } else {
                                $url = add_query_arg( 'wsn_email', $email, $url );
                                ?>
                                <a class="button btn alt <?php echo apply_filters( 'wsn_join_waitlist_button_classes', 'wsn_join_btn_class', $is_loggedin ); ?>" href="<?php echo esc_url( $url ); ?>"><?php echo get_option( 'join_btn_label', esc_attr__( 'Join waitlist', 'in-stock-notifier' ) ); ?></a>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php
            }
        }
    }
    return ob_get_clean();
} add_shortcode( 'form__data', 'form__data' );
```

On the single product page, it is displayed without error, but on the product editing page, the following error is received :

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_children() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\ii\wp-content\themes\hello-elementor-child\functions.php:2233 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\ii\wp-content\themes\hello-elementor-child\functions.php(1292): form__data() #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\ii\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(308): customize_woocommerce_available_variation(Array, Object(WC_Product_Variable), Object(WC_Product_Variation)) #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\ii\wp-includes\plugin.php(205): WP_Hook->apply_filters(Array, Array) #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\ii\wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\includes\class-wc-product-variable.php(392): apply_filters('woocommerce_ava...', Array, Object(WC_Product_Variable), Object(WC_Product_Variation)) #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\ii\wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\includes\class-wc-product-variable.php(312): WC_Product_Variable->get_available_variation(Object(WC_Product_Variation)) #5 C:\xampp\htdocs\ii\wp-content\themes\hello-elementor-child\functions.php(2638): WC_Product_Variable->get_available_variations() #6 C:\xampp in C:\xampp\htdocs\ii\wp-content\themes\hello-elementor-child\functions.php on line 2233
```

This is the code box that is placed on the product edit page :

```
function wsn_product_tab_callback() {
    global $post;
    $wsn_product = wc_get_product( $post->ID );
    $product_type = $wsn_product->get_type();
    $pid = intval( $wsn_product->get_id() );
    if ( 'auto-draft' === $post->post_status ) {
        render_notice( __( 'Not published' ), __( 'Product is not published yet.', 'in-stock-notifier' ) );
        return;
    }
    switch ( $product_type ) {
        case 'simple':
            if ( $wsn_product->is_in_stock() ) {
                render_notice( __( 'In-stock' ), __( 'Product is already available for sale.', 'in-stock-notifier' ), 'dashicons-smiley' );
            } else {
                waitlist_box( $pid, $wsn_product );
            }
            break;
        case 'variable';
            $variations = $wsn_product->get_available_variations();
            for ( $i = 0; $i < count( is_countable( $variations ) ? $variations : [] ); $i ++ ) {
                $pid = intval( $variations[ $i ]['variation_id'] );
                $variation_product = wc_get_product( $pid );
                ?>
                <div id="wsn_callback" class="wc-metaboxes-wrapper wsn-product-variation-head">
                    <div class="woocommerce_variation wc-metabox closed">
                        <h3>
                            <div class="handlediv" title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Click to toggle', 'woocommerce' ); ?>"></div>
                            <strong><?php echo sprintf( esc_attr__( 'Waitlist for %s', 'in-stock-notifier' ), $variation_product->get_formatted_name() ); ?></strong>
                        </h3>
                        <div class="wc-metabox-content woocommerce_variable_attributes ">
                            <div class="wsn_product_container" id="<?php echo intval( $pid ); ?>">
                                <div class="waitlist_data" id="<?php echo intval( $pid ); ?>">
                                    <?php
                                    if ( $variation_product->is_in_stock() ) {
                                        render_notice( __( 'In-stock' ), __( 'Product is already available for sale.', 'in-stock-notifier' ), 'dashicons-smiley' );
                                    } else {
                                        waitlist_box( $pid, $variation_product );
                                    }
                                    ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php
            }
            break;
    }
}

function wsn_product_tab() {
    add_meta_box( 'wsn_product', esc_attr__( 'In-Stock Notifier', 'in-stock-notifier' ), 'wsn_product_tab_callback', 'product', 'normal', 'high', null );
} add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'wsn_product_tab' );
```

When I disable the `woocommerce_available_variation` hook, the product edit page problem is solved, but I want to have both.

Comment: The `global $product;` hasn't been defined when you register the shortcode. If you look at your product edit page, you see that `wc_get_product` is being used to get the product related to the post. Alternatively it looks like the `woocommerce_available_variation` exposes the `$product` in the filter. You could pass that to your `form__data` function. Does it need to be a shortcode, though?

Answer (score 0):

The global `$product` variable isn't declared in the scope that you're using it in. Though the `woocommerce_available_variation` filter exposes the current `$product` in the second param. Modify you `form__data` function to accept a `$product` argument and pass the `$product` to the `form__data` function within the filter.

```
<?php

function customize_woocommerce_available_variation( $variation_data, $product, $variation ) {
    $variation_data['form__data'] = form__data($product);
    return $variation_data;
} add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'customize_woocommerce_available_variation', 10, 3 );

function form__data($product) {
    $variations_id = $product->get_children();
    foreach ( $variations_id as $variation_id ) {
        $variation = wc_get_product( $variation_id );
        if ( ! $variation->is_in_stock() ) {
            $product_url = get_permalink( $variation_id );
            $url = wp_nonce_url( $product_url, 'action_waitlist' );
            $url = add_query_arg( 'wsn_waitlist_users', $variation_id, $url );
            $url = add_query_arg( 'wsn_waitlist_users' . '-action', 'register', $url );
            $url = add_query_arg( 'var_id', $variation_id, $url );
            $is_loggedin = is_user_logged_in();
            ob_start();
            if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
                    ?>
                    <div class="wsn-form">
                        <div class="wsn-form__inner">
                            <div class="wsn-form__content">
                                <div class="wsn-form-message">
                                    <div class="wsn-form-message-item"><?php echo apply_filters( 'wsn-out-of-stock', esc_html__( 'Out of Stock', 'in-stock-notifier' ), $is_loggedin ) ?></div>
                                    <div class="wsn-form-message-item"><?php echo apply_filters( 'wsn-guide-desc', esc_html__( 'Provide your Email so we can email you when product comes in-stock.', 'in-stock-notifier' ), $is_loggedin ); ?></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="wsn-form-field">
                                    <input type="text" placeholder="<?php echo __( 'Enter Your Email Address...', 'in-stock-notifier' ); ?>" id="wsn_waitlist_email" name="wsn_email" class="wsn-input-field wsn-waitlist-email-field"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="wsn-form__footer">
                                <a class="<?php echo apply_filters( 'join_btn_classes', 'button btn alt wsn-submit-form wsn-submit-form--disabled', $is_loggedin ); ?>" href="<?php echo esc_url( $url ); ?>"><?php echo esc_attr__( 'Join waitlist', 'in-stock-notifier' ); ?></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php
            } else {
                $user = wp_get_current_user();
                $email = $user->user_email;
                $waitlist = wsn_get_waitlist( $variation_id );
                $joined = wsn_check_register( $email, $waitlist );
                ?>
                <div class="wsn-form">
                    <div class="wsn-form__inner">
                        <div class="wsn-form__content">
                            <div class="wsn-form-message">
                                <div class="wsn-form-message-item">
                                    <?php echo esc_html__( 'Out of Stock', 'in-stock-notifier' ); ?>
                                </div>
                                <div class="wsn-form-message-item">
                                    <?php echo $joined ?
                                        esc_html( apply_filters( 'wsn_leave_waitlist_message_text', esc_attr__( 'We\'ll notify you as soon as item is back in stock.', 'in-stock-notifier' ), $is_loggedin ) ) :
                                        esc_html( apply_filters( 'wsn_join_waitlist_message_text', esc_attr__( 'Join the waitlist, so we can notify you as soon as the item is back in stock.', 'in-stock-notifier' ), $is_loggedin ) );
                                    ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="wsn-form__footer">
                            <?php if ( $joined ) {
                                $url = add_query_arg( 'wsn_waitlist_users' . '-action', 'leave', $url );
                                $url = add_query_arg( 'wsn_email', $email, $url );
                                ?>
                                <a class="button btn alt wsn_button <?php echo esc_html( apply_filters( 'wsn_leave_waitlist_button_classes', 'wsn_leaveclass', $is_loggedin ) ); ?>" href="<?php echo esc_url( esc_attr( $url ) ); ?>"><?php echo get_option( 'leave_btn_label', __( 'Leave waitlist', 'in-stock-notifier' ) ); ?></a>
                            <?php } else {
                                $url = add_query_arg( 'wsn_email', $email, $url );
                                ?>
                                <a class="button btn alt <?php echo apply_filters( 'wsn_join_waitlist_button_classes', 'wsn_join_btn_class', $is_loggedin ); ?>" href="<?php echo esc_url( $url ); ?>"><?php echo get_option( 'join_btn_label', esc_attr__( 'Join waitlist', 'in-stock-notifier' ) ); ?></a>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php
            }
        }
    }
    return ob_get_clean();
}
```